# Decompose $R^3$ as a direct sum of two subspaces that are each stable under φ.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space V = $R^3$ with the linear map φ: V → V given by the
matrix
\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\\-2&-1&1\\-3&-1&2\end{bmatrix}
Decompose $R^3$ as a direct sum of two subspaces that are each stable under φ.

I have literally no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\phi$ is diagonalizable and has three distinct eigenspaces. Hence you can write $V=E_{\lambda_1}\oplus E_{\lambda_2}\oplus E_{\lambda_3}$ where $E_{\lambda_i}$ denotes the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Clearly $\phi(E_{\lambda_i})\subset E_{\lambda_i}$ since these are eigenspaces.